# Bootstrap button menu responsive doesn't work in Django project

Tags: django, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm writing a project of Django. I created a static folder in my application accueil. Te button doesn't show the menu when browser resized. It's a free template that i downloaded, when i used it in my project of Django it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr" class="no-js">
{% load static %}
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accueil/css/Styles_accueil.css' %}" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accueil/css/bootstrap.css' %}" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accueil/css/normalize.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accueil/css/main.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accueil/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accueil/css/animate.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accueil/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accueil/css/style.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accueil/css/responsive.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'accueil/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js' %}"></script>
```

```
<header id="home">

  <!-- Main Menu Start -->
  <div class="main-menu">
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="{% static 'accueil/img/correspondx.png' %}" /></a> -->
          </div>

          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li> <a href="/accueil/">Accueil</a></li>
              <li> <a href="/apropos/">A propos</a></li>
              <li><a href="/contacternous/">Nous contacter</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Main Menu End -->



</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to add link to bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js in the head section also... jQuery would be needed also.

You can download it or use a CDN:

Comment: It was already download. I inserted it but it's not working. <script src="{% static 'accueil/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

Comment: You added jQuery also? Both jquery and bootstrap.js need to be added

Comment: I inserted all the JQuerry files<script src="{% static 'accueil/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'accueil/js/jquery.smooth-scroll.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'accueil/js/jquery.sticky.js' %}"></script>

Comment: It's work when i did not add the index file in the project Django. But in the project, when i run the server and call the page, the button menu when i resize the page doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please add this link before you added bootstrap.min.js? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: here's the template that i downloaded : https://www.pfind.com/goodies/demo/Bizium/

Comment: Bootstrap is now added as a tag, that'll help people discover this question... Bootstrap plugs in the works pretty easily... You may want to check https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp